# How to solve "Failed: Converting circular structure to JSON in Protractor Test "

Tags: arrays, json, protractor

I am trying to extract some values from our webapp and store the values in a  JSON file. Below is my code.

When I run the script, I get the error "Failed: Converting circular structure to JSON" . But I did not find any circular reference on this script. The variables are independent or it looks like to me.

```
require('..\\waitAbsent.js');
require("../node_modules/jasmine-expect/index.js");
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var G = globalVariables;
var util = require('util')

var fs = require('fs');

let StudentData = 'StudentData.json';

describe('Test for Json Data', function (){

    beforeAll(function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.get(G.loginMain);
    });

    it('test for Json file creation', function(){

        var SubmitButton = $('#submitButton').getAttribute('id').then(function(SB){
        return(SB)

        });

        var UserName = $('#username').getAttribute('id').then(function(UN){
        return UN;
        });

        let Data = {    
            a: UserName,
            b: SubmitButton,    
        };        
        let DT = JSON.stringify(Data);    
        fs.writeFileSync(StudentData ,DT);    
        });    

    it('test for Submit', function(){

        let Uploaded_data = fs.readFileSync(StudentData);

        let Data = JSON.parse(Uploaded_data);

        let c = Data['Submit'];

        console.log(c);

        expect(c).toBe('submitButton');

    })

});
```

How can I overcome this? Is there really any circular reference in this script?

Answer (score 0):

with the help of [update-json-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/update-json-file) I could fix the problem. Now I write each values separately in the Json file and somehow It does not show that circular reference error.

My updated code is as follows:

```
    require('..\\waitAbsent.js');
require("../node_modules/jasmine-expect/index.js");
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var G = globalVariables;
var util = require('util')
const updateJsonFile = require('update-json-file')

var fs = require('fs');

let StudentData = 'StudentData.json';

describe('Test for Json Data', function (){

    beforeAll(function () {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.get(G.loginMain);


    });

    it('test for Json file creation', function(){

        var SubmitButton = $('#submitButton').getAttribute('id').then(function(SB){

        let Data = { SubmitButton : SB };

            let DT = JSON.stringify(Data);

            fs.writeFileSync(StudentData ,DT);

            return(SB)


        });

        var UserName = $('#username').getAttribute('id').then(function(UN){
            updateJsonFile(StudentData, (data) => {

                data.UserName = UN
                return data
            })
;
        return UN;
        });

    });


    it('test for b', function(){


        let Uploaded_data = fs.readFileSync(StudentData);

        let Data = JSON.parse(Uploaded_data);

        let c = Data['SubmitButton'];

        console.log(c);

        expect(c).toBe('submitButton');

    })

});
```